# Can't get keyboard combinations to work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, onkeypress

I have created the following function, which I apply to various inputs in order to restrict what the user can enter in them. While this function is working fine on **`Microsoft Edge`**, I'm facing serious resistance from **`Mozilla Firefox`** which doesn't seem to accept the combinations <kbd>shift + ←</kbd>, <kbd>shift + →</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl + A</kbd> as well as individual keys such as <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>backspace</kbd>, <kbd>delete</kbd>, etc.

I have mended the second issue and managed to make **`Firefox`** accept the individual keys by using the **`isAuxiliaryKey`** variable shown below, but I can't find a way to make it accept the combinations. It seems like Firefox's **`keypress`** functions like a **`keydown`**...

I really want to fix this issue as these combinations are some very common ways to select the text. Is there a way to counter that *malfunction*?

**Code:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript -----  */
function restrict (el, acceptedChars, maxLength) {
  el.onkeypress = function(e) {
    var
      key = String.fromCharCode(e.which),
      isAccepted = isAuxiliaryKey || ((acceptedChars instanceof RegExp) ?
          acceptedChars.test(key) : !!~acceptedChars.indexOf(key)),
      isMaxOrLess = maxLength > el.value.length,
      isAuxiliaryKey =
          (!!~[8, 9, 13, 16, 17, 18, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46].indexOf(e.which)),
      hasActiveSelection = 
          el === document.activeElement && el.selectionStart !== el.selectionEnd;

    return (isAccepted && (isMaxOrLess || hasActiveSelection)) || isAuxiliaryKey;
  }
}

restrict(document.getElementById("text"), /[a-z]/, 4);
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<input id="text" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the fact that nobody has answered, I imagine that this is a problem that has and probably will concern more people in the future. After some trial and error, I finally came up with two solutions that can solve this problem equally well:

**▶ 1<sup>st</sup> Option:**

One way to deal with this, is using the **`keydown`** event instead of the **`keypress`**, because on **`keypress`** there will be characters that share the same **`keyCode`**. For example, for the **`keypress`** event, both <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd><sub>•</sub></kbd> give **`e.which = 46`**. So, if we allow <kbd>Delete</kbd> to be pressed, <kbd><sub>•</sub></kbd> will be allowed as well.

To fix this, we can use:

```
var a = element.onkeydown = function(e) {
    return e;
}
```

Then, we can just change **`e`** to **`a`** in the following line:

```
isAuxiliaryKey = (!!~[8, 9, 13, 16, 17, 18, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46].indexOf(a.which))
```

**Code:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript -----  */
function restrict (el, acceptedChars, maxLength) {
  var a = el.onkeypress = function(e) {
   return e;
  }
  el.onkeypress = function(e) {
    var
      key = String.fromCharCode(e.which),
      isAccepted = isAuxiliaryKey || ((acceptedChars instanceof RegExp) ?
          acceptedChars.test(key) : !!~acceptedChars.indexOf(key)),
      isMaxOrLess = maxLength > el.value.length,
      isAuxiliaryKey =
          (!!~[8, 9, 13, 16, 17, 18, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46].indexOf(a.which)),
      hasActiveSelection = 
          el === document.activeElement && el.selectionStart !== el.selectionEnd;

    return (isAccepted && (isMaxOrLess || hasActiveSelection)) || isAuxiliaryKey;
  }
}

restrict(document.getElementById("text"), /[a-z]/, 4);
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<input id="text" type="text" />
```

---

**▶ 2<sup>nd</sup> Option:**

Instead of using the **`keydown`** event, we can also use **`String.fromCharCode(e.which) === ""`**. This solves the issue of the keys that share the same **`keyCode`**, because even though both keys in our previous example, <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd><sub>•</sub></kbd>, produce **`e.which = 46`**, they have the following difference:

```
DELETE -> String.fromCharCode(46) = ""
.      -> String.fromCharCode(46) = "."
```

So, taking the above into consideration, the issue can also be alleviated by changing the **`isAuxiliaryKey`** variable to the following:

```
isAuxiliaryKey =
    (!!~[8, 9, 13, 16, 17, 18, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46].indexOf(e.which)) && key === ""
```

**Code:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript -----  */
function restrict (el, acceptedChars, maxLength) {
  el.onkeypress = function(e) {
    var
      key = String.fromCharCode(e.which),
      isAccepted = isAuxiliaryKey || ((acceptedChars instanceof RegExp) ?
          acceptedChars.test(key) : !!~acceptedChars.indexOf(key)),
      isMaxOrLess = maxLength > el.value.length,
      isAuxiliaryKey =
          (!!~[8, 9, 13, 16, 17, 18, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46].indexOf(e.which)) && key === "",
      hasActiveSelection = 
          el === document.activeElement && el.selectionStart !== el.selectionEnd;

    return (isAccepted && (isMaxOrLess || hasActiveSelection)) || isAuxiliaryKey;
  }
}

restrict(document.getElementById("text"), /[a-z]/, 4);
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<input id="text" type="text" />
```